# how to pass Id from parent to partial view in asp.net mvc3?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I am trying to pass on an ID from a page to an embedded partialView, how can I pass this in? something like?:

```
@Render.Partial("MyControl",@Model.ID)
```

After how can I read this ID in my partial view?:

```
@model PartialViewModel

@myid = IdFromParent
```

Answer (score 8):

When you pass a variable as the second parameter into the `Partial()` method, that becomes the model for the partial you called.  In this case you are passing the ID as the entire model, so you would just have to use `@Model` to get the ID:

```
@*Page View*@
@model MyModel
...
@Render.Partial("MyControl",@Model.ID)
```

.

```
@* MyControl Partial View *@
@model int

@myid = @Model
```

If you want to pass a `PartialViewModel` type into your partial, you will have to provide that as a property on the Parent ViewModel (the model in your first example), or through the ViewData or ViewBag containers.

Answer (score 2):

You can pass your model id simply like this

```
@RenderPartial("Viewname", model.id)
```

but if you want to send multiple parameters you can do like this

```
@RenderPartial("Viewname", model.id, 
               new ViewDataDictionary { { "parameter", parametervalue } })
```

hope this will solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

```
@Html.RenderPartial("ViewName", Model.Id)
```

or

```
@Html.Partial("ViewName", Model.Id)
```

Answer (score 0):

You must pass to the view the same type of object as the view accepts in its @model directive. So if you are passing an int to the partial view, your @model directive must declare an int.

Or, you could just pass the whole model object, with the id included (of course), and read the id from that object in the partial.

```
Model.id
```